# Flutter build_runner error after upgrading to flutter 3.7.0

Tags: flutter, dart, build-runner

We are executing "flutter packages pub run build_runner watch --delete-conflicting-outputs"
but it throws a "Invalid argument(s): name shouldn't end with a '.'" error. It was working fine until we upgrade flutter version from 3.3.10 to 3.7.0. The file which throws that exception is "logger.dart"

Comment: Please, provide more context and the code of `logger.dart`. Here is [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: how did you solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

change your loggin version to "1.1.0" from your pubspec.lock file. then run flutter pub get command

```
logging:
dependency: transitive
description:
name: logging
sha256: c0bbfe94d46aedf9b8b3e695cf3bd48c8e14b35e3b2c639e0aa7755d589ba946
url: "https://pub.dev"
source: hosted
version: "1.1.0"
```

Comment: Can you give explanation why this cause error?

Comment: Sure it might work but it's a workaround, it's not actually solving the issue

Answer (score 8):

Maybe you made the same mistake like me.

My error came from using two dots side by side in the file.

For example

```
shared_preference_helper..dart
```

change to

```
shared_preference_helper.dart
```

Comment: That sounds very funny, but this was my case! 
Thank you.

Comment: this saved lots of potential wasted time. thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The issue was because if any file you created has two dot  "`..`" in my case

> i had created `cart_item..dart` file

If you are on vscode type (windows)

> `Cntr +Shift + F`

and  search in vs code for `..dart` and rename to `.dart` it will solve your issue

Answer (score 1):

You need to check your file folder I got the same error due to one of my file was mistakenly written as

```
app_tags..dart
```

just remove one dot(.) and run the command again.
I hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes got the same result. Thank you